# XMl Deserializise StackOverflowException

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

I am trying to deserialize a class from an allready saved .xml file.The problem is as soon as I use `get{...} set{...};` the code throws a StackOverflow Exception. Do I create an infinite loop with this piece of code? Because I couldn't track down a loop with halting points.

The class:

```
 [Serializable]
public class AddOn
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("Name")]
    public string Name { set; get; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public ProcessStartInfo Info {
        set { Info = value; }
        get {
            Info.Arguments = args;
            Info.Arguments = Path;
            return Info;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("Arguments")]
    public string args { set; get; }
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("Path")]
    public string Path { set; get; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public List<Process> ChildProcess = new List<Process>();

    public AddOn(string Name, ProcessStartInfo Info)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Info = Info;
        args = Info.Arguments;
        Path= Info.FileName;
    }

    public AddOn() { }
}
```

Where the

```
[XmlIgnore]
    public ProcessStartInfo Info {
        set { Info = value; }
        get {
            Info.Arguments = args;
            Info.Arguments = Path;
            return Info;
        }
    }
```

`get{...}` function throws the StackOverflowException.

I do Ignore the ProcessStartInfo because I was unable to serialize this type in the first place and therefore created the two strings args and Path.

Code which should return the deserialized List of Addons:

```
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<AddOn>));

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);
            var addons = (ObservableCollection<AddOn>)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            reader.Close();
            return addons;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this call

```
 public ProcessStartInfo **Info** {
    **set { Info = value; }**
    get {
        Info.Arguments = args;
        Info.Arguments = Path;
        return Info;
    }
}
```

calls itself leading to the overflow

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that! Apart from that line I totally screwed up the get get part which refered to the ProcessStartInfo itself. That created the loop.